# c# search string in txt file

Tags: c#, string, file-io

I want to find a string in a txt file if string compares, it should go on reading lines till another string which I'm using as parameter.

Example:

```
CustomerEN //search for this string
...
some text which has details about the customer
id "123456"
username "rootuser"
...
CustomerCh //get text till this string
```

I need the details to work with them otherwise.

I'm using linq to search for "CustomerEN" like this:

```
File.ReadLines(pathToTextFile).Any(line => line.Contains("CustomerEN"))
```

But now I'm stuck with reading lines (data) till "CustomerCh" to extract details.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your pair of lines will only appear once in your file, you could use

```
File.ReadLines(pathToTextFile)
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("CustomerEN"))
    .Skip(1) // optional
    .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("CustomerCh"));
```

If you could have multiple occurrences in one file, you're probably better off using a regular `foreach` loop - reading lines, keeping track of whether you're currently inside or outside a customer etc:

```
List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> current = null;
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
{
    if (line.Contains("CustomerEN") && current == null)
        current = new List<string>();
    else if (line.Contains("CustomerCh") && current != null)
    {
        groups.Add(current);
        current = null;
    }
    if (current != null)
        current.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: If you need case insensitive search check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 14):

You have to use `while` since `foreach` does not know about index. Below is an example code.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

Console.Write("Input your search text: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();

System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader("SampleInput1.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains(text))
    {
        break;
    }

    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Line number: {0}", counter);

file.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You don't really need to know the index.

Comment: He need to find first string, wich appears only after other keyword.

Comment: And there is no reason you couldn't put the counter in a foreach as well if you wanted to.

Comment: Every other solution proposed reads the entire file into memory and holds it there until the search is complete. This is the only one that carefully manages memory with a stream while performing the search.

Answer (score 4):

With LINQ, you could use the `SkipWhile` / `TakeWhile` methods, like this:

```
var importantLines = 
    File.ReadLines(pathToTextFile)
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("CustomerEN"))
    .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("CustomerCh"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you whant only one first string, you can use simple for-loop.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToTextFile);

var firstFound = false;
for(int index = 0; index < lines.Count; index++)
{
   if(!firstFound && lines[index].Contains("CustomerEN"))
   {
      firstFound = true;
   }
   if(firstFound && lines[index].Contains("CustomerCh"))
   {
      //do, what you want, and exit the loop
      // return lines[index];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked a little bit the method that Rawling posted here to find more than one line in the same file until the end. This is what worked for me:

```
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(pathToFile))
                {
                    if (line.Contains("CustomerEN") && current == null)
                    {
                        current = new List<string>();
                        current.Add(line);
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("CustomerEN") && current != null)
                    {
                        current.Add(line);
                    }
                }
                string s = String.Join(",", current);
                MessageBox.Show(s);
```