# Finding text between lines in text file

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code in a text file:

```
static const char* g_FffectNames[EFFECT_COUNT] = {
"Fade In and Fade Out",
"Halloween Eyes",
"Rainbow Cycles"
};
```

I can use `g_FffectNames[EFFECT_COUNT]` as a starting point to search in this big text file. But I need to get the things within quotes (e.g Halloween Eyes or Rainbow Cycles).

What is the best way to get those text in C#? I would also have to assume that there are more code on top of this file (before the `static const`) and also toward the bottom (after the  `};` ) and that spacing between characters such as `= {`  or  `};` is optional to the user.

Should I compress all of these lines into one string and start the search or should I use some sort of regex matching to make this easier?

Comment: This isn't C# code.  That looks like C++.

Comment: @Amy It looks like OP is writing a parser in C# that reads C declarations.

Comment: I think the C++ is in the text file, although why one would need to parse such a file escapes me.

Comment: Have you tried something? The first and last sentence of your description indicate that you have an idea of how to start - why not write a bit of code and update your question when you get stuck.

Comment: Amy, the code in the text file is in C++, But I need to find text between those lines in C# and then append new items in quotes afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expressions to parse input file:

```
var input = /* file content */;
var regex = new Regex("^\\s*\"(?<row>[^\"]+)\\s*\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var values = regex.Matches(input)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["row"]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working based on this post:

[c# search string in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856471/c-sharp-search-string-in-txt-file)

```
public string readText()
        {
           string test = string.Empty;
           var mytext = File.ReadLines("C:\\temp\\test_search.txt")
                .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("g_FffectNames[EFFECT_COUNT]"))
                .Skip(1)
                .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("};"));

            foreach (var line in mytext)
            {
                test += line;
            }

            return test;
        }
```