# Check if text exists in text file

Tags: c#, if-statement, text, streamwriter

I'm trying to figure out if the text URL that I get from current URL exists in 'linkx.txt', if it does then show a message, if it doesn't then write to text file. however, when I run this code program writes to text file twice before recognizing the text exists.

[working code]

```
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    string linkx = @"Desktop\linkx.txt";
    string url = "";
    if (keyData == Keys.F1) { Application.Exit(); return true; }
    else if (keyData == Keys.F2) { url = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri; return true; }

    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(linkx))
    {
        string texxt = url;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(linkx);
        bool matched = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
        {
            if (texxt == lines[x])
            {
                sr.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("there is a match");
                matched = true;
            }
        }
        if (!matched)
        {
            sr.Close();
            using (StreamWriter wriite = File.AppendText(linkx))
            {
                wriite.WriteLine(url);
                MessageBox.Show("url copied!");
                return true;    // indicate that you handled this keystroke
            }
        }
    }
    // Call the base class
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: `lines.Contains(textxx)` Note this will check that `textxx` matches the **entirety** of a line - it won't match if it was (for example) only **part** of one of the lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# search string in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856471/c-sharp-search-string-in-txt-file)

Comment: @emsimpson92 Of course it does, but it won't match a word in a line of individual entry but rather the whole line. `String.Contains` does not work the same way `Array.Contains`.

Comment: That's true, but if the URL doesn't exist in the file he wants to write it to the file, so It's most likely a text file full of URLs

Comment: If you are reading a very large text file, you may want to read it line by line  and do the search on each line.  There's no need to read the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"when I run this code program writes to text file twice before recognizing the text exists"*

The main problem with your code is in this condition:

```
for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length - 1; x++)
```

You are looping through all  the lines **except the last one**, which is likely the one you're searching for in this case.

To resolve this, just remove the `- 1` from your exit condition.

---

With that being said, your code can be simplified greatly if you use the static `ReadLines` and `AppendAllText` methods of the `File` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches the specified file for the url and adds it if it doesn't exist.
/// If the specified file does not exist, it will be created.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">The path to the file to query.</param>
/// <param name="url">The url to search for and add to the file.</param>
/// <returns>True if the url was added, otherwise false.</returns>
protected static bool AddUrlIfNotExist(string filePath, string url)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.Create(filePath).Close();

    if (!File.ReadLines(filePath).Any(line => line.Contains(url)))
    {
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, url);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then this method could be used in your code like:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F1) { Application.Exit(); return true; }

    if (keyData == Keys.F2)
    {
        if (AddUrlIfNotExist("linkx.txt", webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("url copied!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("there is a match");
        }
    }

    // Call the base class
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot simpler than what you've got. If you've just got an array of strings you can use [Array.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015.aspx).

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("links.txt");

if (!lines.Contains("google.com")) {
  File.AppendAllText("links.txt", "google.com");
}
```

Comment: This is still prone to the same problem OP has. Use `ReadAllText` and `String.Contains` instead.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I think the OP's problem is that he's not looping through all the lines...he quits just before the last one

Comment: @RufusL: That is one of the problems. The other is that there is no guarantee that `texxt` will ever equal any line. What if a line begins with a space?  "    google.com" and you search for "google.com". Will it find it with `Array.Contains`? Or `texxt == lines[x]`?

Comment: True, my only clue was he said, *"when I run this code program writes to text file twice before recognizing the text exists"*